# AcquireTokenSilent() fails

Tags: .net, winforms, authentication, .net-4.7.2

I am writing a WinForms client which is connecting to an azure WebAPI.

the program fails to call **`AcquireTokenSilent`** with a specific account.  I always get this message:

*"You are trying to acquire a token silently using a login hint. No account was found in the token cache having this login hint."*

However, a call of `AcquireTokenInteractive` with the same account works.

**Here is the preparation:**

```
IPublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(ClientID)
        .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantID)
        .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
        .Build();
string[] scopes = { "user.read" };

AuthenticationResult result;
```

**Now this part fails:**

```
result = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, "office@mydomain.com").ExecuteAsync();
```

**However, this part works:**

The interactive dialog is showing me the same account as above, "office@mydomain.com".

```
result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am seeing the same error.

Comment: @Turbo Unfortunately not. If you can solve it, please let me know. We put the project on hold and will try it now again with .net 6.

Comment: In my case, I am using MSAL.PS module, which is a wrapper around .NET's MSAL. I was getting the same error. But then I just abandoned the idea of passing the loginhint. and also abandoned the idea of managing silent vs interactive login. I just let the library handle it. So, the first time it prompts me interactively, and next time onwards it automatically silently fetches the token. I am using `Get-MSALToken -ClientId <clientid> -TenantId <tenantid> -Scope <scope>` I know it's so different from your case, but I just wanted to mention because I got the exact same error when using LoginHint.